# Ionic 3 android permissions internet

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, android-permissions, ionic-native

I'm writing an app that sends requests to a REST API.

The **API calls work in the web browser**, but not in the emulator and not on a device.

Ionic CLI 4.4.0

Cordova 8.1.2

What i did:

I use android-permissions like on this [side](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions/):

app.modules.ts

```
import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
  ],
  entryComponents: [
  ],
  providers: [
    AndroidPermissions
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

api-call.ts

```
import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions';
export class ApiCallPage {

    constructor(private androidPermissions: AndroidPermissions) {
        this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.INTERNET).then(
            result => console.log('Has permission?', result.hasPermission),
            err => this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.INTERNET)
        );
    }
}
```

The **target device** (device and emulator in AVD manager) has **API 22 (Android 5.1)**.

config.xml

```
<access origin="*" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" spec="1.0.0" />
<engine name="android" spec="^7.1.1" />
```

The last one (engine name) is probably for the cordova-android version and does not have to be 5.1. In **package.json** is under dependencies `"cordova-android": "^7.1.1"`.

- /platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
- /platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

...both files includes (not written by hand):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

It is **not a CORS problem**. The REST API runs on a different server than the web browser and it works with the web browser.

I think I did everything. Is something missing or wrong?

What do you have to do to have Ionic (cordova) Internet access?

**[UPDATE]**
The app info shows me the permissions that the app has full network access. Now I'm at a loss.

[image: screenshot CAT S30 App-Info]

In the API, I log every request at boot time. A request of the app from the device does not arrive. The app in the browser arrives.

Answer (score 1):

It was a CORS issue, but not on the API side, but on the client side.

In the config.xml `<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />` solves my problem.

Take a look at [github ionic-team issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/14410)

For me it was Android 5.1 & 8.0.